# Cert Mapping Domanin Accounts

Tags: powershell, remote-access, winrm

I want to add a Cert Mapping entry like this:

```
  winrm create winrm/config/service/certmapping?Issuer=1212131238d84023982e381f20391a2935301923+Subject=*.example.com+URI=* @{UserName="USERNAME";Password="PASSWORD"}
```

But how can I use a domain User for Username and Password? Is this possible and how to configure that?